# for any partition of $N^+=A\cup B$

Tags: calculus, analysis

for any partition of $N^+=A\cup B$,which $A$and$B$ both are infinite set , for any $c\in R^+$, prove that we can always find $a_1<a_2<...\in A, b_1<b_2<...\in B$ satisfied 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=c$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: enumerate $A = \{x_n\}$ and $B = \{y_n\}$. Then $x_n \to \infty$ and $y_n \to \infty$.  Eventually one of the fractions 
$$ \frac{x_1}{y_1},\ \frac{x_2}{y_1},\ \frac{x_3}{y_1}, \cdots$$
will be greater than $c$. Label the first such fraction $\dfrac{x_N}{y_1}$. Eventually one of the fractions $$\frac{x_N}{y_1},\ \frac{x_N}{y_2},\ \frac{x_N}{y_3}, \cdots$$
will be less than $c$.

Now play ping-pong.